# concatenate json objects with jq

Tags: json, jq

I am new with jq and I have these json output of an app:

```
{
  "Woonkamer": {
    "currentTemperature": 21.8,
    "battery": 75,
    "isFailed": false
  }
}
{
  "Hal": {
    "currentTemperature": 19.5,
    "battery": 48,
    "isFailed": false
  }
}
{
  "Bijkeuken": {
    "currentTemperature": 18.4,
    "battery": 56,
    "isFailed": false
  }
}
```

I want them to join to one json object like:

```
{
  "Woonkamer": {
    "currentTemperature": 21.8,
    "battery": 75,
    "isFailed": false
  },
  "Hal": {
    "currentTemperature": 19.5,
    "battery": 48,
    "isFailed": false
  },
  "Bijkeuken": {
    "currentTemperature": 18.4,
    "battery": 56,
    "isFailed": false
  }
}
```

I cannot get figured out how to do that with jq (I read the manual),

Can someone help me?

Comment: How big is the JSON?

Comment: @Inian It is about 1000 characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jq](/questions/tagged/jq)'s [`add`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#example33), this will concatenate all the input objects;

```
// Multiple variables holding objects
jq -s add <<< "$j1 $j2 $j3"

// Multiple files holding objects
jq -s add file1 file2 file3

// Command output with multiple columns
command | jq -s add
```

### Manually

You can add multiple columns by hand like so;

```
jq -s '.[0] * .[1] * .[2]' file1 file2 file3
```

### Result

Both options result in:

```json
{
  "Woonkamer": {
    "currentTemperature": 21.8,
    "battery": 75,
    "isFailed": false
  },
  "Hal": {
    "currentTemperature": 19.5,
    "battery": 48,
    "isFailed": false
  },
  "Bijkeuken": {
    "currentTemperature": 18.4,
    "battery": 56,
    "isFailed": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer worked for me. I piped the result to the following jq command:

`code` | jq -s '.[0] * .[1] * .[2]'